# HDFS compression at the block level

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

One of the big issues with HDFS is compression: If you compress a file, you have to deal with splittable compression.  Why does HDFS require you to compress an entire file, and not instead implement compression at the HDFS block level?

That would solve the problem: a 64 MB block is read or written in a single chunk, it's big enough to compress, and doesn't interefere with operations or require splittable compression.

Are there any implementations of this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm speculating here, but I can see several problems.

HDFS contains a feature called [local short-circuit reads](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/ShortCircuitLocalReads.html). This allows the datanode to open the block file, validate security, and then pass on the *filedescriptor* to the application running on the same node. This completely bypasses any file transfer via HTTP or other means from HDFS to the M/R app (or to whatever HDFS app is reading the file). On performant clusters short circuit reads are the norm, rather than an exception, as processing occurs where the split is located. What you describe would require the reader to comprehend the block compression in order to read the block.

Other considerations relate to splits that span blocks. Compressed formats in general lack random access and require sequential access. Reading last few bytes from a block, to make up a split that spans on the next block, could be as expensive as reading the entire block, due to compression.

I'm not saying block compression is impossible, but I feel is more complex that what you expect.

Besides, block compression can be [transparently delegated to filesystem](https://serverfault.com/questions/617648/transparent-compression-filesystem-in-conjunction-with-ext4).

And, last but not least, better compression formats exists at data layers above HDFS: [ORC](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC), [Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/).